# How to find number of periods in a loan using javascript

Tags: javascript, math, calculator

How come the following function does not work for values of loan amount that exceed 6-digits and why does it produce incorrect results

e.g. if I input following

```
Loan amount: 1,000,000
Interest Rate: 1.09
Monthly Payment: 1,500
```

Result is: 85.39

When I enter more than 7 digit it returns **NaN** e.g. Loan amount: **10,000,000**

```
function myFunction()
{
    rte = eval (1.09)/1200;
    pmt = eval (1500);
    amt = eval (1000000);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=(Math.log(1+(rte/(pmt/(amt)-rte)))/Math.log(1+rte))/12;
}
```

**You can check here** [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yvBBm/)

Comment: Why in the name of everything holy do you use `eval()` with a single integer parameter?

Comment: I am reading those value from textbox so used eval() if you removed that it doesn't matter result is not changing in this formula.

Comment: Any Idea why it does show NaN ? when amount is greater than 7 digit

Comment: Your formulas for NPER is incorrect, please see this web for the correct one http://finance-formulas.com/pva_present_value_of_annuity.html and please do not use 1.09 as the rate value as it will be taken as 109% rather than 9%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, lets take a close look at your code, as it has some mistakes. First, we refactor it:

1. Output has nothing to do with your question so we remove this part from function.
2. Global variables are bad, and hardcoding is bad, so lets make them function arguments.
3. No need to use `eval` here at all.
4. myFunction is useless name.

Result:

```
function calcLoan(rte, pmt, amt)
{
    return (Math.log(1+(rte/(pmt/(amt)-rte)))/Math.log(1+rte))/12;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = calcLoan(1.09/1200, 1500, 1000000);
```

Next, we can work on the function code itseft:

1. Lets remove redundand braces
2. Lets make argument names shorter, so it will look more like Math
3. Lets (temporary) add some debug info.

Result:

```
function calcLoan(r, p, a)
{
    return Math.log( 1 + (r / (p/a - r) ) ) / Math.log(1 + r)  / 12;
}

function debugLoan(r, p, a)
    return [ p/a, Math.log( 1 + (r / (p/a - r) ) ), 1 + (r / (p/a - r) ), Math.log(1 + r) ];
}

// call
calcLoan( 1.09/1200, 1500, 1000000 );
//85.38526703746216

// call with bigger number
calcLoan( 1.09/1200, 1500, 10000000 );
// NaN, because we supply negative value to Math.log

// see it yourself
debugLoan( 1.09/1200, 1500, 10000000 );
// [0.00015, NaN, -0.19780219780219777, 0.0009079210482536982]
```

As you see in [`Math.log` reference] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log) - you will always get NaN, if you supply negative value as argument.

So, not only your code is bad, but also **the formula is wrong**.